# Python Tuple save to file

Tags: python, dictionary, key, tuples

```
def save(val):
    w = open(val, "w")
    for key in self.bok.iterkeys():
        w.write(self.bok[key])
        w.write(";")
        w.write(key[0])
        w.write(";")
        w.write("\n")
    w.close()
```

If my dict looks like

```
bok = {(1,2,3,4,5) : 22}
```

i would like to write all the tuples in my key to the value in a file, so it looks like

```
22;1
22;2
22;3
etc...
```

Currently I only get the first value in my tuple to write to a file, `22;1`. I know I get it by `key[0]` but I cant really change it.

Is there any way to make this work?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered python's `pickle` module for this? Or you could write it out as `JSON`

Comment: The little used shelve module is great too.

Comment: Why are you writing this to a file? Are you just saving data to load later (look at [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html))? Are you outputting to as a CSV with semicolons as delimiters (look at [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html))?

Comment: Cant really use pickle cause my document has to be like 22;1 \n 22;2 \n 22;3 etcetc i dont know if u can configure that with csv or pickle :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to nest a second for loop here:

```
for key in self.bok.iterkeys():
    for subkey in key:
        w.write(self.bok[key])
        w.write(";")
        w.write(subkey)
        w.write(";")
        w.write("\n")
w.close()
```

Also, consider using some string formatting:

```
for key in self.bok.iterkeys():
    for subkey in key:
        w.write("{};{};\n".format(self.bok[key], subkey))
w.close()
```

Comment: Also consider the [`with`](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) keyword to open the file.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend serializing the dictionary.The `pickle` module provides support for this! An example program for you:

```
    import pickle ##Import the pickle module
    bok = {(1,2,3,4,5) : 22} #Define the dictionary
    w = open(val, "wb")#Open the file
    pickle.dump(bok, w)#Dump the dictionary bok, the first parameter into the file object w.
    w.close()
```

You must open the file in "wb" mode because, pickles are binary data.
After running this code the file `val` will contain binary data.

To bring the dictionary back:

```
    import pickle#import the pickle module
    w=open(val, 'rb')#Open the file
    bok=pickle.load(w)#Assign the recreated object to bok
```

Basically `pickle.dump()` translates objects into binary data that can be written to files.
`pickle.load()` reads the given file and returns the reconstructed object.

This works for many python objects besides dictionaries, like lists and booleans.

Python docs for `pickle`:http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pickle.html